# PHP can't see <input>

Tags: php, html, mysqli

When I clicked on delete nothing happen.

Why can't it see the submit in PHP?

This is my function

```html
// this code after query and fetch
echo "<table border='1'>
       <form method='POST'>
        <tr>
        <th>Books</th>
        <th>Action</th>
        </tr>";
        foreach($result as $row){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['nameOfBook'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" ."<input type='submit' name='delete' value='Delete' method='post' >" . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        
        echo "</table>";
        echo "</form";
       
        if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
            die("SS");
        }
```

Comment: `$statment` is not defined anywhere in your function (apart from the fetchall), therefore no results = no delete

Comment: You missed to close the `<input>` tag.

Comment: @Syscall - close doesn't matter, helps, but doesn't matter ultimately  as it's always a self closed tag

Comment: You need to add more of your code, you have the input, but is it in a form? If not - it needs to be else there is nothing to submit

Comment: @SamSwift `>` does matter. In every tag.

Comment: @bigwolk - it does usually help, but with browsers like chrome and FF (even edge... *shudder*) they are clever enough to know where the tag ends (as another begins) and closes them automatically, so yes, important, but ultimately don't matter

Comment: put the submit inside a `<form></form>` tag

Comment: Curious why you aren't putting the third echo in your foreach loop in continuous apostrophes. Splitting a string down the middle is completely aimless. The issue is with the undefined variable as mentioned above though. I'm hoping that if you're relying on user input for that SQL query that it's sanitised.

Comment: Wouldn't your submit buttons also need some identifying information about which book to delete?

Comment: Yeah, it should probably include some part of the $row array, maybe $row['nameOfBook'] but if you actually look at his delete function, it's just a die();

Comment: Use form tag like this echo "<table border='1'>
   <form method='POST'>
    <tr>
    <th>Books</th>
    <th>Action</th>
    </tr>";
  
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . "bookname" . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" ."<input type='submit' name='delete' value='Delete' method='post' " . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    echo "</form>";
    echo "</table>";
    //here nothin happen when i submit
    if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
        die("SS");
    }

Comment: @Sachin now with form its work but when i click on delete it reload the page .. its not display die("ss"). why ????

Comment: hope you added form method =post , if already added then can you pls  post your updated code.

Comment: please check my update

Answer (score 0):

Character list of defects;
From comments; you are not closing your html input tag using the `>` or `/>`

You use the variable `$statment` but this is never defined in your function, from the name of the function it calls (*and the fact it's tagged!*), it looks like you're using mysqli, so adding

```
$statment = mysqli_query($connectin, "your query here");
$statment->fetchAll();
```

Would help resolve that issue, even passing `$statment` into the function
This is ultimately your main issue here

Make sure that you are using form tags around your inputs and give it some defining feature as to what you are deleting, else it could delete all

You add `method="post"` to your input - the form is where this should be, the form contains the method and not the inputs, they are only there for data gater / send

If this was me doing this - rather than a "submit" type input, I'd use a button and have a JavaScript (jQuery) onclick event, for example;

```
<?
function getBooks($start = 0, $limit = 2)
{
    global $connection; // Add your link into this to do queries
    $sql_start = $start * $limit;
    $sql_limit = $limit;
    // Do your query and define $statment
    $statment = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT something FROM a_table");
    $result = $statment->fetchAll();

    // Rather than printing lots separate, add to a return value and do this once
    $return_value = "";
    $return_value .= "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Books</th>
    <th>Action</th>
    </tr>";
    foreach($result as $row){
        $return_value .= "<tr>";
        $return_value .= "<td>" . $row['nameOfBook'] . "</td>";
        // Rather than have "submit", use a button for this and add an onclick event
        $return_value .= "<td>" ."<input type='button' name='delete' value='Delete' onclick='deleteBook({$row['bookid']})' />" . "</td>";
        $return_value .= "</tr>";
    }
    $return_value .= "</table>";

    if(isset($_POST['book_to_delete'])){
        die("SS");
    }

    return $return_value;
}
?>

<form method="POST" action="#" id="book_list">
    <!-- Add a hidden input to hold the value you want to delete -->
    <input type="hidden" id="book_to_delete" name="book_to_delete" />
    <?
    print getBooks();
    ?>
</form>

<script>
    function deleteBook(bookId)
    {
        // Set the book_to_delete and submit the form with this
        jQuery("#book_to_delete").val(bookId);
        jQuery("#book_list").submit();
    }
</script>
```